# Check if in "dev" mode inside a Controller with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, controller, containers

When using dev mode with a **Symfony2.x** application, one usually works in locale. Hence, such function does not works as expected (for instance, try to get the current IP under localhost). This could be a problem, e.g. when one try to use such ip-based web service. Hence, **I just want to know how to check inside a controller if the Symfony2 application is running in *dev* mode or not**.
In that way one can set the behavior of the controller depending by the mode.

Any idea?

Comment: Can I suggest you to take a look at my answer which I think is more appropriate than the accepted one?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To get the current environment in a `Controller` you can use:

```
$this->container->getParameter('kernel.environment');
```

So you just put that in an `if()` statement to check if it equals to `dev`.

Answer (score 28):

As of Symfony **2.5** it could be done as:

```
$this->container->get('kernel')->getEnvironment();
```

Directly asking Kernel of it's environment looks nicer than searching for parameter.

Comment: I think it's related to passing Container anywhere outside Dependency Injection Container. That's a bad practise due to tree circularity. I could provide full answer if you need.

Comment: @TomášVotruba: Please do. From my point of view retrieving such meta from container is harmless, as it just uses reference to the container which is `public` property of DIC. If Symfony developers wanted it to be considered bad practice, they would rather create shortcut methods for encapsulation.

Comment: Done, I've tried to added some explation you've requested. It's another topic and it would make answer less readable, so I tried to make it short. Definitelly check the link, it explains a lot :)

Comment: "If Symfony developers wanted it to be considered bad practice..." - These changes takes time, because many people including leader have to agree upon them. That's why some frameworks used contructor injection by default since 2015 and Symfony waited till late 2017 and Symfony 4.

Comment: @TomášVotruba: Got you point, thanks. However, at the time of writing it was a reasonable option.

Comment: @KinBinary: No argument here. I think my answer will be outdated in 1-2 years with some better replacement.

Comment: @TomášVotruba: Just another day in software development: )

Answer (score 19):

Since you want to know if you are in dev mode (not necessarilly the environment named "dev"), you can retrieve the kernel from the service container and check the `isDebug` method return:

```
$kernel = $this->get('kernel');
$devMode = $kernel->isDebug();
```

As noted [in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html#executing-an-application-in-different-environments) (emphasis is mine),

> Important, but unrelated to the topic of environments is the `true` or `false`
>   argument as the second argument to the `AppKernel` constructor. **This
>   specifies if the application should run in "debug mode". Regardless of
>   the environment, a Symfony application can be run with debug mode set
>   to true or false**. This affects many things in the application, such as
>   displaying stacktraces on error pages or if cache files are
>   dynamically rebuilt on each request. Though not a requirement, debug
>   mode is generally set to true for the dev and test environments and
>   false for the prod environment.
>
> Internally, the value of the debug mode becomes the kernel.debug
>   parameter used inside the service container.

Answer (score 18):

## Symfony 3.3/4/5+ Solution

Here is **2017 and Symfony 3.3+** version using **Constructor Injection**.

Instead of passing you whole application (= container), you could **pass only the parameter you need**:

### 1. Service config

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    App\Controller\SomeController:
        arguments: ['%kernel.environment%']
```

If you don't understand this syntax, [check this post explaining Symfony DI news in before/after examples](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/).

### 2. The Controller

```
namespace App\Controller;

final class SomeController
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $environment;

    public function __construct(string $environment)
    {
        $this->environment = $environment;
    }

    public function someAction()
    {
        $this->environment...
        // any operations you need
    }
}
```

### Why to avoid passing Container in Controller?

The most important thing in the code is **consistency**.

- If you prefer static and service locators (= service you can pass anywhere to get any other service), use it.
- If you prefer constructor injection, tree dependency graph (!= circular dependencies), use it.

Mixing this concept might be ok for you, if you know why you used them that way. But here comes to play [The Broken Window Theory (nicely described version by Coding Horror)](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-broken-window-theory/). Anyone coming to the code **will more likely pick the version that is not intended to use that way**.

#### Ambiguity in the code is the first invitation to legacy code

I've mentored teams of many applications, that started with simple `$this->container` in the code and after couple of years ended up calling me for help, how to rewrite or refactor whole static hell.

Comment: Great, but use `'%kernel.debug%'` instead of `'%kernel.environment%'` and `bool $isDebug` as constructor's parameter.

Answer (score 7):

**Symfony 5.1**

`$this->devEnvironment = 'dev' === getenv('APP_ENV');`

I use this inside of a Symfony service. You will need to add the line `APP_ENV=dev` to .env.local and `APP_ENV=prod` to .env file. Depending on if you have a similar env setup to me

Answer (score 4):

From Symfony 4.1 inside Service

```
class MyService
{
    private $params;
    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }
    public function check($e)
    {
       if($this->params->get("kernel.environment") === "dev") 
       {
            return true;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Symfony 4 and higher, you can use simply :

```
if ($this->getParameter('kernel.environment') === 'dev') {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## For Symfony 4.1+

I prefer to avoid using `kernel` inside my controllers and services.

***services.yaml:***

```yaml
parameters:
    app.environment: '%kernel.environment%'
    ...
```

***Your controller / service:***

```php
class MyService
{
    private $isDev;

    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $appParams)
    {
        $this->isDev = $appParams->get('app.environment') === 'dev';
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        if ($this->isDev)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## For Symfony 4.x and above

If you are using `.env` to store your environment variables, you can access them **in any controller** by simply using **`$_ENV['name-of-variable']`**

For a default installation, there is a `$_ENV["APP_ENV"]` variable available, which will tell you if you are in dev mode or not.

---

Use **`print_r($_ENV);`** to see all the available environment variables.

[ps - This also works for Symfony 3.4]

---

**Reference** - https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/components/dotenv.html

Comment: You shouldn't be using globals in Symfony.

Comment: Agreed. But to check something as trivial as whether we're in Dev mode or not, why not? (Just listing out a possibility here)

Comment: One of the first rules of Symfony best practises, do not use globals. Something like binding an environment variable would be much better: `$appEnv: '%env(APP_ENV)%'`

Comment: you're probably right, but the official docs list this way of accessing `env` variables. Kindly check out the reference.