# With Symfony 2.8, in a custom bundle/library, how do I actually consume a loaded yml config?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, configuration, drupal-8

My experience has been limited to Laravel, which makes loading config settings as simple as `\Config::get('MySiteLibrary.customSetting');` and it loads the structure setting.

I am now in the process of writing a Symfony compatible library to use with a Drupal 8 (which is built on Symfony 2.8) website as well as standalone usage with other projects.

In this library I am writing I need to be able to load environment specific config settings. I have found tons of stuff on how to put everything under `Resources/config/config.yml and services.yml` as well as the `DependencyInjection\Configuration.php` and `MyWhateverExtension.php`. But nothing I have found shows me how to actually use that config throughout your bundle/library.

Can someone please demonstrate this? I am getting tired of reading through the overcomplicated docs for Symfony that do not seem to actually tell you how to use it once it is all wired up.

**UPDATE:**
To be more specific I am creating an API library that can call multiple endpoints pretty easily. The way I want to structure it is so that the calling app can call a central class that orchestrates calls to the endpoints based on what I am doing.

Example: The app needs to create a new customer account (to which 3 different endpoints have to be called). So it calls `API::Customer::Account->create($data);`. The create() method then calls the endpoints in order. These endpoints, in code, are classes I created that know how to deal with said endpoint. To make those endpoints cleaner I am injecting an Adapter class that knows about the details of communicating with the overall API we are calling (the endpoints provide details that a specific to them).

What I want to do is have the dependencies automatically fulfilled for the adapter and for the endpoints when I call them. This means that I configure defaults such as using Guzzle as the primary client tool from a config file. Or that I use x-logger to log everything. The DI container news up those dependencies and returns a fully created instance of the Adapter class. I want to also be able to easily grab some environment-specific config settings from within the Adapter class and possibly elsewhere. And since I am accessing this from 20+ endpoint classes I really don't want to repeat code to inject the configuration in over and over again.

So yes, I do know that Laravel lowers the bar for doing this. I don't expect it to work the same way. What I want to do though is to find a way to load that config in the most minimalist way possible. I should add that the first place I will be using this is in a Drupal 8 project.

This is an example what the code looks like:

```
<?php
namespace SomeCompany\API\Adapter;

use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;
use SomeCompany\API\Exception\ScException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use SomeCompany\API\Interfaces\ConfigInterface;

class SpecificAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, ClientInterface $client) {
    parent::__construct($logger, $client);

    $this->setDefaultSuccessStatus('0'); // From parent class
  }

  public function getAuth() {
    if ($this->shouldUsePrivateToken()) {
      return ConfigInterface::get('SomeCompany.api.auth_common');
    }

    if ($this->shouldUseAnonymousToken()) {
      return ConfigInterface::get('SomeCompany.api.auth_common');
    }

    if ($userToken = self::getUserToken()) {
      return "TOKEN: $userToken";
    }

    throw new ScException('Unable to find the appropriate token for this call.');
  }

  public static function getUserToken() {
    // This part is not ironed out yet. Don't judge me.
    return !empty($_SESSION['user_token']) ? $_SESSION['user_token'] : false;
  }

  public function shouldUseAnonymousToken() {
    // Some rules here the return a boolean
  }

  public function shouldUsePrivateToken() {
    // Some rules here the return a boolean
  }
}
```

This is then used by each of the Endpoint classes...

```
<?php
namespace SomeCompany\API\Endpoint\Customer;

use SomeCompany\API\Data\Account;
use SomeCompany\API\Endpoint\Endpoint;
use SomeCompany\API\Interfaces\AdapterInterface;
use SomeCompany\API\Exception\ScException;

class Accounts extends Endpoint {
  protected $processedResults = [];
  protected static $requiredFields = ['address1', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'phone'];

  public function __construct(AdapterInterface $adapter) {
    parent::__construct($adapter);
    $this->getAdapter()->setUri('customer/accounts');
  }

  public function create($data) {
    if (empty($data) || (!is_array($data) && !is_object($data))) {
      throw new ScException('Unable to create a new account without data.');
    }

    $data = $this->filterParams($data, self::$requiredFields);
    $this->getAdapter()->setMethod('POST');
    $this->getAdapter()->setParams($data);

    $result = $this->getAdapter()->execute();

    if (isset($result->accountId)) {
      return $result->accountId;
    }

    return null;
  }

  protected function filterParams($data, array $required) {
    $data = (object) $data;
    $data->specialSetting = 'SpecialValue'; // Set the SpecialSetting default to "SpecialValue" for companies.

    //Verify required fields are set
    foreach ($required AS $field) {
      if (!isset($data->$field)) {
        throw new ScException("Missing required account field: $field");
      }

      if ($field == 'phone') {
        $data->phone = preg_replace('~.*(\d{3})[^\d]*(\d{3})[^\d]*(\d{4}).*~', '$1-$2-$3', $data->phone);
      }
    }

    if (empty($data->someMarker)) {
      $data->specialSetting  = 'NotSpecial'; // Forced to NotSpecial.
    }

    return (array) $data;
  }
}
```

The endpoints themselves are loaded from a number of classes that orchestrate how they are used.

Maybe I am overcomplicating how to do what I want to do. But I greatly want to reduce code duplication and I see this as being a pretty big issue with what I am doing.

Comment: In fact, do you want to load the yaml configuration according to the environment?

Comment: It's not uncommon to compare a new framework with one that you are more comfortable with and get frustrated because the new one works differently.  Symfony apps depend heavily on service configuration.  You will need to become comfortable with services (which Laravel tends to hide behind facades) in order to have much success.  Consider updating your question with a very specific (and simple) use case.

Comment: I understand this. I am just finding the documentation to be a bit frustrating in the lack of how things are used. It is awesome for stringing up the code though.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998060/check-if-in-dev-mode-inside-a-controller-with-symfony2-x), you can check the environment, like that :

```
$this->container->getParameter('kernel.environment');
```

According to [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html), you can check a parameter loader in parameters.yml :

```
$container->getParameter('mailer.transport');
```

If you want to load an custom configuration file like this :

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;

// ...
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
        $container,
        new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
    );
    $loader->load('services.xml');
}
```

You can parse the custom YAML file like this :

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException;

try {
    $value = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('/path/to/file.yml'));
} catch (ParseException $e) {
    printf("Unable to parse the YAML string: %s", $e->getMessage());
}

// var $value is an associative array
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I have already set all that up configuration-wise. However I am building a library here and breed to access the config from within a library class that is loaded as needed. It doesn't inherit from anything, so $this->container is not applicable.

Comment: In this case, you can use the lastest piece of code in my post, or inject container in your service.